# Perl: cmpthese text vs anonymous sub problems with parameters passed

Tags: perl, parameters, eval, subroutine

If you read about `cmpthese` in the [Perl Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html#SYNOPSIS) module's documentation, it states that `cmpthese` or `timethese` can be used with code in either text or subroutine references. The documentation seems to imply these forms are completely interchangeable:

```
# Use Perl code in strings...
timethese($count, {
'Name1' => '...code1...',
'Name2' => '...code2...',
});
# ... or use subroutine references.
timethese($count, {
'Name1' => sub { ...code1... },
'Name2' => sub { ...code2... },
});
```

I am having difficulties with passed parameters with the string form versus subroutine references form with `cmpthese`. Either the values in `@array` do not get passed or I have a run-time error.

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @array = qw( first second third );

sub target {
    my $str =  $_[0];
    print "str=$str\n";
}

sub control {
    print "control: array[0]=$array[0]\n";
}

my $sub_ref=\&target;
my $control_ref=\&control;

print "\n\n\n";

# ERROR: array does not get passed...
cmpthese(1, {
    'target text' => 'target(@array)',
    'control 1' => 'control()', 
});

# This is OK...
cmpthese(1, {
    'sub code ref' => sub { target(@array) },
    'control 2' => sub { control() },
});

# This is OK too...
cmpthese(1, {
    'target sub' => sub { $sub_ref->(@array) },
    'control 3' => sub { $control_ref->() },
});

# fixed paramenters work:
cmpthese(1, {
    'target text fixed' => 'target("one", "two", "three")',
    'control 4' => 'control()', 
});

# Run time error...
cmpthese(1, {
    'text code ref' => '$sub_ref->(@array)',
    'control 5' => '$control_ref->()',
});
```

All the forms I have work correctly with `eval` so I think this may be an issue with Benchmark? I have used all my google foo to try and find some documented difference between the two forms but I cannot.

Does anyone know the reason that my simple examples above do not seem to work as expected? The comments in the code indicate the problems I am having on OS X, Perl 5.10.0.

Comment: not related to this question, but see if you can upgrade your perl to at least 5.10.1, 5.10.0 has a number of bugs that got fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't looked in too much detail at this, but my guess is that when `Benchmark` evals the strings into code, the lexical variable `@array` is not in scope.  Things would probably work if you made `@array` an `our` variable.

But in general, I find it is easier just to use code refs.

Comment: Replacing `my` with `our` fixed it the first issue. Thanks!!! Any idea why the "control 5" case does not work?

Comment: Are you using `our $control_ref`? `my $control_ref` would be out of scope by the time it is evaluated.

Comment: probably the same reason.  since the refs are in lexical variables, they are not available to the string eval that Benchmark is using

Comment: `our` fixed all "my" issues. Both control 1 and control 5 work as I expect. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

The text passed to `cmpthese` and `timethese` gets propogated to an `eval` statement deep in the bowels of Benchmark. Unless the arguments in the text are literals or global variables, they won't be in scope by the time they are evaluated, and you get a run-time error.

Use the anonymous sub version of the arguments to provide lexical closure for your arguments and all will be well.